# Best way to start a new activity from a clicked listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-intent, android-activity

I have an array that successfully shows as a listview as the main activity. I've been using many tutorials in the past few days to try to find out the best way to start different activities from items clicked on this listview. I've seen everything from switch statements to calling a class by a variable, but nothing seems to work. I would possibly use an if statement but my list is over 120 entries. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put the class as a parameter of the item ?

```
    package com.ybi;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class YbiListActivity extends ListActivity
    {
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
        {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            ClickableItem[] values = new ClickableItem[1];

                            // here you can add your label and your activity
            values[0] = new ClickableItem("Hello", YbiListActivity.class);

            ArrayAdapter<ClickableItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ClickableItem>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            ClickableItem item = (ClickableItem) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(YbiListActivity.this, (Class<?>) item.itemClass);
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        private class ClickableItem
        {
            public String itemLabel;
            public Object itemClass;

            public ClickableItem(String ilabel, Object iclass)
            {
                itemLabel = ilabel;
                itemClass = iclass;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString()
            {
                return itemLabel;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create two new arrays in arrays.xml (list_items and list_item_activities)
Then, when an item is selected, you can use its index to find the associated activity.

```
<string-array name="list_items">
  <item>ExampleActivity</item>
  ...
</string-array>

<string-array name="list_item_activities">
  <item>com.example.app.ExampleActivity</item>
  ...
</string-array>
```

To explain a bit more, you would use the list_items to create the list:

```
String[] list = getResources().getStringArray("list_items");
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
  // add the item
}
```

Then when the item is clicked:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
  String[] activities = getResources().getStringArray("list_item_activities");
  // activities[position] is what you would use
}
```

Comment: Hmm... your answer reminded me of 2D arrays. I'll have to give it a try. Thanks